# Calculate domain, asymptotes (oblique, vertical and horizontal), extremes, curvature of the following function?

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

The function is:

$$ f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1-x}{x+2}\right) $$

I managed to calculate my domain: <-2,1>. My intersection with x is $ln(\frac{1}{2}) $ and with y is $-\frac{1}{2}$. I don't know how to calculate asimptotes since there is ln. I should be using L'Hôpital's rule but i cannot manage to find the solution.

Comment: what have you done already?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I edited my question. Can you help me at all?

Answer (score 1):

at first it must be $$\frac{1-x}{x+2}>0$$ and this gives $$-2<x<1$$
asymptotes are $$x=-2$$ and $$x=1$$
the intersection with the x-axes is not right, you must solve the equation
$$1=\frac{1-x}{x+2}$$ for $x$